# Call to a member function get_cellmap() on null

Tags: laravel, dompdf, barryvdh

I was using barryvdh/laravel-domPDF and came across the error

> call to a member function get_cellmap() on null

I'm using Laravel 8.42.1 and PHP 8.0.3.

```
<div>
    <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
      <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
          <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">
              <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
                <div class="content-evenly">
                  PRIVATE AND CONFIDENTIAL
                </div>
                <div class="content-evenly col-span-1 sm:col-span-2 border-solid border-4 border-light-blue-500">
                  <div class="employee float-right m-10 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        @foreach($teams as $team)
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                          {{$team->companyName}}
                        </th><br>
                        <th>
                          {{$team->street}}
                        </th><br>
                        <th>
                          {{$team->compound}}
                        </th><br>
                        <th>
                          {{$team->suburb}}
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                      @foreach($employees as $employee)
                  </div>
                  <div class="employee float-left m-10 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 ">
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                          {{$employee->name}} {{$employee->surname}}
                        </th><br>
                        <th>
                          {{$employee->role}}
                        </th><br>
                        <th>
                          {{$employee->idNumber}}
                        </th>
                        <th>
                          {{$employee->phone}}
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                  @endforeach
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>           
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get\_cellmap() issue with DomPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128372/get-cellmap-issue-with-dompdf)

Answer (score 1):

Computed Styles might also cause that issue, on my case a display:block on the table tag was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your html structure there are some limitations with dompdf for example some tags are not supported.
I think you should use only table tag with thead,th,tbody,tr:
if you want to read more about the limitations there is the link:
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#user-content-limitations-known-issues

Comment: thank you very much. i changed to snappy and the issues were resolved. i also think it was the structure of the html